# How to use iOS swift hero framework for transition between two viewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, transition, uiviewanimation

I have **two viewcontrollers**. First is **tableviewcontroller** and another is **detailviewcontroller**. Tableviewcontroller shows list of images. When user clicks the image, i want to create a transition as shown below. Does anyone have related project? I think this kind of transition is known as "**Shared Element Transition**". If I'm wrong help me correcting it. Help me using with [**"Hero Library"**](https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero) but alternatives are fine as well.
[image]

Comment: There is very nice tutorial on hero library: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9inorgaUJmQ

Comment: Its working for present modally but the nav bar is not showing. I tried adding nav programatically but the animation is lost.

Comment: @user3853770 did u find a solution?

Comment: @Rezwan yes, you just have to enable hero and set same heroid to both images.

Comment: @user3853770 thank you, but that works for "Modal" type only. not working for "Show(Push)" type segue.

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable Hero on your UINavigationController (in storyboard or do it programmatically)...

You can enable Hero programmatically by  using the following:

```
navigationController.hero.isEnabled = true
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how do we allow Hero - I have been reading about it and I have not find any command or in the storyboard to specifically allow it.

Comment: Your answer is Incomplete , please elaborate